# Error when creating a table in MySQL with a Foreign Key Constraint

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE OFFICES
 (OFFICE INTEGER NOT NULL,
 CITY VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
 REGION VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
 MGR INTEGER,
 TARGET DECIMAL(9,2),
 SALES DECIMAL(9,2) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (OFFICE),
 FOREIGN KEY HASMGR (MGR)
 REFERENCES SALESREPS
 ON DELETE SET NULL);
```

Prouduces the following error:

> ```
> #1239 - Incorrect foreign key definition for 'foreign key without name': 
> Key reference and table reference don't match
> ```

Comment: `REFERENCES SALESREPS` - tablename only is too low, fields not specified.

Comment: Welcome to DBA.SE. Please have look at [ask] and maybe even [mvce]. We don't have much to go with. Please [edit] your question and include an introduction, possible referenced tables and the definitions thereof. Without further details, we will be having a hard time assisting you.